# Does main tag go before or after h1 heading?

Tags: html

Concerning ARIA, it seems that the heading should come first, before the `main` tag, and focus the content of a particular webpage. Or should the `main` tag come before the heading?

Comment: head tag before body tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<main>` tag specifies the main content of a document.

The content inside the `<main>` element should be unique to the document. It should **not contain any content that is repeated across documents** such as sidebars, navigation links, copyright information, site logos, and search forms. [W3Schools `main` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_main.asp)

I guess the heading is repeated content, so put that before the `<main>` tag.

Yet your title states **before or after `<h1>` heading**, it all depends on the value of `<h1>` (does it get repeated or not?)

Comment: <h1> would not be repeated

Comment: If <h1> is part of the main content, you should put <h1> in the <main> element. You can get some more info about <main> [here](http://html5doctor.com/the-main-element/)

Comment: thanks you the good answer. Am trying to make an accessible website and need all the help I can get.

Comment: If you still have some questions regarding this issue you might want to update the question or simply ask a new one. If your question is answered in a satisfied way you may want to accept and or upvote the answer. Good Luck with your future code.